# How to tell a UITextField to use the NumberPad Keyboard in code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I created a UITextField in code, now I have now idea how to define the keybaord that should appear ? I just get the standard keybboard, but I need a numberpad ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set the `keyboardType` property to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`.

Answer (score 12):

Obj-C:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

And simply use `.numberPad` in Swift.

Answer (score 6):

Swift:

```
textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also easily do this in the XIB file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Keyboardtype like this:

```
.keyboardType(UIKeyboardType.numberPad)
```

here with some context:

```
@State var text : String = "" 
TextField("text", text: self.$text).keyboardType(UIKeyboardType.numberPad)
```